# Mobile menu css

Tags: css

What's the best way to
achieve going from a menu like this :
[image]

to this when screensize reaches a certain width :

[image]

So basically change certain texts to icons.

Is the only way pre-defining it and changing the display property in css from none to block ? or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it. I would start by in the correct order list all the elements for mobile and desktop together then display:none the ones you want to be hidden on desktop and go from there. Could do it with JS but that's a lot more work and could look wonky on load.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on what @MPortman said, it'd be better to have a clear idea at the start;

I would use **CSS Media Queries** to do that.

You can for istance just use the display:none starting from a specific width.

The web inspector is useful to see some "common breakpoints" but you **don't have to target** @media rules at **specific devices**, it'd be better narrow to your desktop browser window and observe the natural breakpoints for your content.

Media queries are a good way to make responsive pages, you can hide or show elements from a certain width of the device used (mobile/desktop for example).

You can use them to set a minimum width and a maximum width.

For example:

```
/* If the screen size is between 768px and 900px (included), hide the element */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  div.example {
   display:none
  }
}
```

Will hide the element on a screen bigger than 768px and 900px.